# why is my database emptying when i start/stop/restart uWSGI running a flask-restful app

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector-python

Whenever I start/stop/restart the following service

```
[Unit]
Description=Application
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/website/backend
Environment="PATH=/var/www/website/backend/myenv/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --http-socket :5000 --plugin python38 --module wsgi:app  --virtualenv /var/www/website/backend/myenv/ --processes 5 --threads 20
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Most of the tables in the database that is accessed by the flask-restful app are emptied.
This loss isn't limited to just data entered by the application.

Has anyone experienced this?
I've tried a few different things including moving from mariadb to vanilla mysql 8.
Also tried changing the storage engines to MyISAM from InnoDB in case it was a rollback related issue but nothing has worked.

connecting to mysql via:

```
import util

import mysql.connector

def get_conn():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="admin",
        password="pass/>",
        database="db"
    )
    return conn
```

typical insert into db:

```
def create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, country, promo_date, membership='default', avatar='default.png') -> (bool, str):
    conn = get_conn()
    db = conn.cursor()
   
    db.execute('select email from users where email=%s',(email,)) 
    user = db.fetchone()
    if user is not None:
        return (False, 'Email is already registered')
    
    vid = make_unique_id('verifications', db)
    sql = 'insert into verifications (id, email, verificationDate) values (%s, %s, %s)'
    val = (vid, email, None)
    db.execute(sql, val)
    db.execute('commit')
    sql = 'insert into users (email, country, firstName, lastName, membership, promoDate, avatar, password, registerDate, receivePromoEmails, verified) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'
    val = (email, country, first_name, last_name, membership, promo_date, avatar, password, util.datenowutc(), True, None)
    db.execute(sql, val)

    db.execute('commit')
    db.close()
    conn.close()

    try: 
        send_verification_email(email, vid)
    except:
        pass

    return (True, 'Successfully added user')
```

typical endpoint:

```
class RegisterUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('email').add_argument('password')
            parser.add_argument('first_name').add_argument('last_name')
            parser.add_argument('country').add_argument('promo_date').add_argument('captcha')
            args = parser.parse_args()

            if not util.verify_captcha(args['captcha']):
                return {'status': 'failure', 'message': 'captcha failed'}

            email = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['email'])
            password = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['password'])
            fname = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['first_name'])
            lname = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['last_name'])
            country = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['country'])
            promo_date = sec.decryptAsymmetric(args['promo_date'])

            if not util.is_valid_email(email):
                return {'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Email is invalid'}

            if promo_date != '':
                promo_date = datetime.fromisoformat(promo_date)
                if promo_date < datetime.now(timezone.utc):
                    return {'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Event date must be in the future'}
                
            status, message = db.create_user(email, password, fname, lname, country, promo_date)
            if status:
                return {'status': 'success', 'message': message}
            return {'status': 'failure', 'message': message}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return {'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Unknown server error. Please try again shortly.'}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, considering Linux services don't have a vendetta toward database information, I would start by looking in the code of the app that the service is starting.

Comment: i know. it doesnt make sense but i've been over every line several times. I never execute truncate statements but that seems to be whats happening. and not during the execution of the rest endpoints in the flask-restful app but specifically when I start/stop/restart the service

Comment: I'm not that familiar with uWSGI, however I am with Linux, Python and MySQL. There has to be initialization logic causing this. Perhaps try sharing some of your code from the app, especially the startup portions that interact with the database.

Comment: added code detail

Comment: i dont know what it was but i started from scratch on a debian 10 server and now it's all good

Comment: Super strange, I don't see anything in the code you have shared. Glad it's working on Debian for you.